# How can I pass parameters from one page to another page

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium+java junit. I want to pass the session id from the login page to another page.

Is this possible?

Comment: what kind of parameter are you wanting to store?  An IWebElement, a property of the IWebElement, or a bool?  Knowing the parameter you want to pass between pages would help in getting a much more accurate answer.

Comment: Please edit this question for clarity, or it will likely be closed in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
driver.manage.all_cookies
```

That will return all active cookies, the session cookie should be in that